# How to handle async subshell exit

Tags: bash, shell, background-process, subshell

Say I have this:

```
set -e;

(
    docker stop notifier-server
    docker rm -f notifier-server
    exit 1  # explicitly exit with non-zero
) &

wait;

echo 'we are here now'
```

will we always get to the echo line, even if the subshell exits with non-zero? I assume so, since it's a backend process/subshell?

What's the right way to look at this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would not terminate the current shell session since *no non-zero exit status is returned to it*.  The result in the calling shell of starting a background job is always zero.

If you had used `wait "$!"` or `wait -n` ("wait for next job to finish"), then the shell session *would* have terminated since `wait` would have returned the exit status of the job that it waited for, which is non-zero.

See `help wait` in `bash`.

Answer (score 3):

It is not related to the process being a background process, it is related to the exit status of the `wait` command.

From `help wait`:

> If ID is not given, waits for all currently active child processes, and the return status is zero.

```
$ bash -exc '(sleep 1; exit 1) & wait ; echo done'
+ wait
+ sleep 1
+ exit 1
+ echo done
done
```

> If the -n option is supplied, waits for the next job to terminate and returns its exit status.

```
$ bash -exc '(sleep 1; exit 1) & wait -n; echo $?:done'
+ wait -n
+ sleep 1
+ exit 1
```